# 'Unresolved reference' inspections are not shown below unreachable code in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

'Unresolved reference' inspections are not shown below unreachable code.

[image: screenshot1]

```py
aaa() #inspection shown

if False:
  print(1)

aaa() #inspection not shown
bbb() #inspection not shown
```

It seems the same for early-evaluatable statements.

[image: screenshot2]

```py
aaa() #inspection shown

if 0 > 1:
  print(1)

aaa() #inspection not shown
bbb() #inspection not shown
```

But seems not always.

[image: screenshot3]

```py
aaa() #inspection shown

if 0 > 0.1:
  print(1)

aaa() #inspection shown
bbb() #inspection shown
```

I checked with many verions of PyCharm from 2017.X to

```
latest(
PyCharm 2020.3.3 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-203.7148.72, built on January 27, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.9.1+11-b1145.77 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 10.15.7
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 725M
Cores: 16)
```

, and also checked some of computers of my colleagues, all same.

Anyone have same problem or how to solve or work-around this problem?

Comment: *"work-around this problem"* - Remove that unreachable code?

Comment: Haha, one of cool idea. I just changed inspection level of 'unreachable code' from warning to error.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from [PyCharm Code Inspection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/code-inspection.html)

> Every inspection has a severity level — the extent to which a problem
> can affect your code. Severities are highlighted differently in the
> editor so that you can quickly distinguish between critical problems
> and less important things. PyCharm comes with a set of predefined
> severity levels and enables you to create your own.

and [Static Code Analysis](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/StaticCodeAnalysis.pdf) (IntelliJ IDEA)

> 1. Finding probable bugs
> 2. Locating the “dead” code
> 3. Detecting performance issues
> 4. Improving code structure and maintainability
> 5. Conforming to coding guidelines and standards
> 6. Conforming to specifications

There are many severity levels for code analysis: `errors > warnings > weak warnings > server problems > typos`.

I guess their code analysis mechanism is when it runs on the fly or manually and finds `the “dead” code` then it stops analyzing `unresolved reference`. This explains why Pycharm does not highlight the below `unresolved reference` errors unless you put the rest of code in the `else` statement. For the last case, it highlights the `unresolved reference` because it fails to detect the `unreachable code` which I also do not understand.

Although Python interpreter can detect these problems when we run the script, I agree that PyCharm should fix this problem.